# Why sum is not working in MYSQL while using left join?

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, sum, left-join

```
**Here is my sample data:**

Users table:

    +------------+--------------+-------------+
    | user_id    | user_name    | credit      |
    +------------+--------------+-------------+
    | 1          | Moustafa     | 100         |
    | 2          | Jonathan     | 200         |
    | 3          | Winston      | 10000       |
    | 4          | Luis         | 800         | 
    +------------+--------------+-------------+

Transaction table:
+------------+------------+------------+----------+---------------+
| trans_id   | paid_by    | paid_to    | amount   | transacted_on |
+------------+------------+------------+----------+---------------+
| 1          | 1          | 3          | 400      | 2020-08-01    |
| 2          | 3          | 2          | 500      | 2020-08-02    |
| 3          | 2          | 1          | 200      | 2020-08-03    |
+------------+------------+------------+----------+---------------+
```

**And I have to find the net amount in each customer account and tell whether net amount is less than 0 or not after transaction**s;

Result table:

```
+------------+------------+------------+-----------------------+
| user_id    | user_name  | credit     | credit_limit_breached |
+------------+------------+------------+-----------------------+
| 1          | Moustafa   | -100       | Yes                   | 
| 2          | Jonathan   | 500        | No                    |
| 3          | Winston    | 9900       | No                    |
| 4          | Luis       | 800        | No                    |
```

I am trying this code:

```
select user_id, user_name, sum(users.credit + k.credit) credit, case
when ifnull((users.credit + k.credit), users.credit) < 0 then "Yes"
else "No"
end as credit_limit_breached
from users
left join (select id, sum(credit)credit 
from (select paid_by as id, sum(-amount)credit from transaction group by id
union
select paid_to as id, sum(amount)credit from transaction group by id) tem
group by id) k
on k.id = users.user_id
```

**It gives null value for Luis (he has not done any transactions), so what is wrong.**

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code, including smallest representative example input as code; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. Give the least code you can that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) For SQL that includes DBMS & DDL (including constraints & indexes) & input as code formatted as a table. [ask] Pause work on the overall goal, chop code to the 1st expression not giving what you expect & say what you expect & why.

Comment: @philipxy yes will make sure, thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your current query is rather close. You can use `coalesce()` to assign a default value of `0` to users that have no transaction at all. Also, you don't need (nor want) `sum()` in the outer query: a simple addition is enough.

So:

```
select 
    u.user_id, 
    u.user_name, 
    u.credit + coalesce(k.credit, 0) credit, 
    case when u.credit < coalesce(k.credit, 0) then 'Yes' else 'No' end as credit_limit_breached
from users u
left join (
    select id, sum(credit) credit 
    from (
        select paid_by as id, sum(-amount) credit from transaction group by id
        union all
        select paid_to as id, sum(amount) credit from transaction group by id
    ) t
    group by id
) k on k.id = users.user_id
```

Another approach is a correlated subquery:

```
select 
    x.*,
    case when credit < 0 then 'Yes' else 'No' end as credit_limit_breached
from (
    select
        u.user_id,
        u.user_name,
        u.credit + (
            select coalesce(sum(case when u.user_id = t.paid_for then amount else - amount end), 0)
            from transaction t
            where u.user_id in (t.paid_by, t.paid_for)
        ) as as credit
    from users u
) x
```

Answer (score 0):

Unpivot the transactions and then join and aggregate:

```
select user_id, sum(credit) as credit, sum(debit) as debit
from ((select paid_to as user_id, sum(amount) as credit, 0 as debit
       from transactions t
       group by paid_to
      ) union all
      (select paid_from as user_id, 0, sum(amount)
       from transactions t
       group by paid_from
      )
     ) t
group by user_id;
```

Then join in for the final result:

```
select u.*, u.credit + t.credit - u.debit,
       (case when u.credit + t.credit - u.debit < 0 then 'yes' else no' end)
from users u left join
     (select user_id, sum(credit) as credit, sum(debit) as debit
      from ((select paid_to as user_id, sum(amount) as credit, 0 as debit
             from transactions t
             group by paid_to
            ) union all
            (select paid_from as user_id, 0, sum(amount)
             from transactions t
             group by paid_from
            )
           ) t
      group by user_id
     ) t
     on t.user_id = u.user_id
```